# OfflineAudioContext FFT analysis with chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, chromium, web-audio-api

i'm trying to build a waveform generator that get audiofile amplitudes values and display them to a canvas as quick as possible (faster than realtime) in javascript. so i use the OfflineAudioContext / webkitOfflineAudioContext , load the file and start the analyse. 
the waveform is to fill a wide canvas.

i analyse buffer in a processor.onaudioprocess function. (i guess it's the way it works ?)

it works fine in firefox but i've got an issue in chrome : it seems it "jumps" over much analyse to finish it works as soon as possible and only returns a few coordinates (something like 16).

here is the jsfiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/bestiole/95EBf/

```
// create the audio context
if (! window.OfflineAudioContext) {
    if (! window.webkitOfflineAudioContext) {
        $('#output').append('failed : no audiocontext found, change browser');
    }
    window.OfflineAudioContext = window.webkitOfflineAudioContext;
}
//var context = new AudioContext();
var length = 15241583;
var samplerate = 44100;
var fftSamples = 2048;
var waveformWidth = 1920;

var context = new OfflineAudioContext(1,length,samplerate);
var source;
var splitter;
var analyser;
var processor;
var i=0;
var average;
var max;
var coord;

processor = context.createScriptProcessor(fftSamples, 1, 1);
processor.connect(context.destination);

analyser = context.createAnalyser();
analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0;
analyser.fftSize = fftSamples;

source = context.createBufferSource();
splitter = context.createChannelSplitter();
source.connect(splitter);
splitter.connect(analyser,0,0);

analyser.connect(processor);

context.oncomplete = function(){
    $('#output').append('<br />complete');
}

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', "http://www.mindthepressure.org/bounce.ogg", true);
request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
request.onload = function(){
    $('#output').append('loaded ! ');
    context.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(buffer) {
        $('#output').append('starting analysis<br />');
        processor.onaudioprocess = function(e){
            var data =  new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
            analyser.getByteFrequencyData(data);
            average = getAverageVolume(data);
            max = Math.max.apply(Math, data);
            coord = Math.min(average*2,255);
            coord = Math.round((max+coord)/2);
            ctx.fillStyle=gradient;
            ctx.fillRect(i,255-coord,1,255);
            console.log(i+' -> '+coord);
            i++;
        }
        source.buffer = buffer;
        source.start(0);
        context.startRendering();
    }, onError);
}
request.send();

function onError(e) {
    $('#output').append('error, check the console');
    console.log(e);
}

function getAverageVolume(array) {
    var values = 0;
    var average;
    var length = array.length;
    for (var k = 0; k < length; k++) {
        values += array[k];
    }
    average = values / length;
    return average;
}
```

(here is another version that forces waveform to fit in 1920px wide and generate a waveform data for who is interested : http://jsfiddle.net/bestiole/E3rSx/ )

i really dont get the point, how doesn't chrome treat every part of the audio file ?

thanks for any help !

Comment: Can confirm this with Canary 34 too. It seem to do a brute-force if the current call isn't able to finish within the given time, but that's a guess.. How is it behaving if you run it real-time (normal context)? (moving the gradient fillStyle to global scope gives a little better result)

Comment: it works fine in real-time context. thanks for the fillstyle trick !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome has a bug in script processors in offline mode.

Comment: i get the same issue in safari, i guess it's a webkit / blink thing.

which seems corroborated by https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=113274 and http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-audio/2013JulSep/0110.html : the main audio thread doesn't wait for the processor to compute its tasks before proceeding to the next block of sample frames...
too bad i cannot find a confirmed bug report yet.

thanks for your answer

Comment: did you ever find a bug report for this? Still having issues when rendering out an oscillator in chrome v36. Works perfectly in latest firefox v30.

Comment: Bug report in Chromium, I really need this to work, I wonder when it will be resolved: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=374339

Comment: janesconference: I doubt that will get fixed, as the goal is to replace scriptprocessors with Audio Workers (which *will* work in offline by default)

Comment: @cwilso: audio workers will be really cool, as they will remove the annoying buffer latency os scriptprocessors, as you point out here: https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/113
But this will hold back *a lot* of possible applications until they are implemented, probably in terms of years instead of months. This is inconvenient, considering that the Firefox implementation works. Don't want to criticize at all, just a (somewhat bitter) consideration.

Comment: I recall having a conversation with @pauladenot about this on the WG, but I don't recall the details.  I don't know what Firefox is doing, but hopping the threads and waiting for responses from the main thread to onaudioprocess calls is kinda icky.  :)