# OfflineAudioContext FFT analysis still broken in chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, fft, html5-audio, audiocontext

I have been trying to use OfflineAudioContext and the FFT analyzer in chrome with a script processor but I am running into the same issue that this person has: [OfflineAudioContext FFT analysis with chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21011701/offlineaudiocontext-fft-analysis-with-chrome)

In that SO answer, someone pointed out this bug report: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=113274 but it is over a year old!

My questions are: does anyone know if this will be fixed anytime soon and should I file a bug elsewhere? Is that bug report (that is a year old) still being looked at? Or better yet, maybe someone knows a workaround? My code is essentially the same as the jsfiddle on that SO link.

It's really sad that this stuff doesn't work in chrome but it does in Firefox.

Comment: Still looking for a workaround (if it is even possible). However I made a bug report here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=374339 Apparently it is set to be in the next "Milestone"... whatever that means.